# Unable to see azureStorageBinding binding under WCF-Custom after installing Azure Storage Adapter (BizTalkFactory Codeplex adapter)

Tags: azure-storage, biztalk, biztalk-2016

We are currently working on a BizTalk server migration project (from 2013R2 to 2016) and in the process need to install Azure Storage Adapter (publisher BizTalkFactory Codeplex Team) so as to fetch files from Azure blob storage into BizTalk.

This is working fine with 2013R2 version however after installing the same msi on BizTalk Server 2016 Enterprise version we are not able to see azureStorageBinding under WCF-Custom adapter bindings.

Also I tried using WCF-WebHttp adapter with azureStorageBehaviour however when I apply changes it says "Error saving properties. (System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException) Configuration binding extension 'system.serviceModel/bindings/azureStorageBinding' could not be found. Verify that this binding extension is properly registered in system.serviceModel/extensions/bindingExtensions and that it is spelled correctly"

I verified the machine.config file too and azureStorageBinding is present.

Note - When I install the same msi with BizTalk Server 2016 Developer version, it works fine.

Please let me know if I'm missing something here or any probable causes for this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: i believe azure storage adapter is still a beta version?

Comment: yes, it's a beta version  but it works fine with 2013r2 and 2016 developer versions based on my observation.

Comment: Any thoughts on this issue? We are still facing this.

Comment: biztalk 2016 machine config should be in this framework location NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config

Comment: yes @EdBangs, I verified the machine.config file at the mentioned location and it does have azureStorageBinding configuration.

Comment: both 32 and 64 bit?

Comment: when i install the msi it only adds configuration under 32-bit machine.config file (as is the case when i install on 2013r2 also) however even after adding the configuration manually in 64-bit .config file also, azureStorageBinding isn't loading in WCF-Custom dropdown.

Comment: can you share here the binding section info?

Comment: Here you go - 
<bindingElementExtensions>
<add name="azureStorageAdapter" type="BizTalkFactory.Adapters.AzureStorage.AzureStorageAdapterBindingElementExtensionElement, BizTalkFactory.Adapters.AzureStorage, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6ca9668807bd3a5f" /> </bindingElementExtensions>

<bindingExtensions>
 <add name="azureStorageBinding" type="BizTalkFactory.Adapters.AzureStorage.AzureStorageAdapterBindingCollectionElement, BizTalkFactory.Adapters.AzureStorage, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6ca9668807bd3a5f" />
</bindingExtensions>

Comment: <client>
 <endpoint binding="azureStorageBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" name="azure" />
</client>

Comment: try add this on your biztalk config <configuration> <startup> <supportedRuntime version="4.0"/> </startup> </configuration>

Comment: this already exists in 32 and 64 bit BizTalk config files.